# MYSQL - How to compare multiple columns for matching categories

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-columns

I have a table named PRODUCTS with 3 columns for three different categories, i want to select all products which have any of the 3 values in any of the 3 columns.
What i'm trying to do is show related products based on any of the 3 categories.

Example table:

> id,name,cat1,cat2,cat3
>
> 1,Keyboard,2,8,4
> 2,Mouse,2,NULL,NULL
> 3,Monitor,16,2,NULL

Let's supose i'm viewing ITEM id=1, i want to do a query to show the other 2 products that have category number 2 in any of the 3 columns.

How do I do that?

Thank you very much,
Andres

Comment: i don't think this is an optimal design to start with.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id != 1 AND (cat1 = 2 OR cat2 = 2 OR cat3 = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, for any given ID, find the other "siblings" that have that same category as the chosen one, in their categories?

select id as chosen_id, p1.cat as p1_cat, p2.cat as p2_cat, p3.cat as p3_cat
from products p1, products p2, products p3
where
p1.cat = p2.cat
and
p1.cat = p3.cat
// and various other qualifications like, it's not a repeat
p1.id != p2.id
p1.id != p3.id
p2.id != p3.id
etc.
// you can also do `join products p3 on p3.cat = p1.cat` instead of 
// the verbose way I did it

BTW this is a bad idea performance-wise. Best done programmatically and not in SQL.Any time you're dealing with cursor-ish queries like this, just do it with arrays in code, not in SQL

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try and see what happens... I guess I better find the way to do it using PHP